# Azure python function accessing csv file form blob containers inputblob.name is None

Tags: python, azure, function

I try to access a csv file form my azure unfction following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python.

Input file:

1. storage account: stpartnerdata001
2. Blob containers: data01
3. Folder: imdb-extensive-dataset
4. File: IMDb movies.csv

I created a DataConnectionSettings01 in the function app Application setting with the value Connection String from key1 from the stpartnerdata001 storage account.

```
"name": "inputblob",
"type": "blob",
"path": "data01/imdb-extensive-dataset/IMDb movies.csv",
"connection": "DataConnectionSettings01",
"direction": "in"
```

I tried to run the function to printing out the file name:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Function called')
    logging.info('input name: %s', inputblob.name)
    return func.HttpResponse("This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

When exeuction the funciton I always receive input name: None.
How can I access the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, looks like for now this is not available. This is a known issue:[Blob Input Binding doesn't receive the blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/576).

The description is the metadata of input blob binding(name, length etc) is not provide by the function host, the best way is to use the [python storage SDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) to implement it.

The blob input binding could only get the blob content.

Comment: Hi George Chen, thanks a lot for your help. One additional point: differentiate between folder and blob containers and set the path accordingly. I want to do a proof of concept if Azure functions with python and pandas can be used to do transformations on a csv file. Any other resources you can poin tme to? Considering that the Microsoft azure documentation does not seem to be up to date?

Comment: Please provide more information, what problem you got now? Or what feature you want to use?